# I built a library with Maven. How do I find its jar so that I can use it without Maven?

Tags: java, maven-3, xgboost

I need to use the [xgboost4j package](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/) in my Java project. The installation instructions say that I must use Maven, but my project is a simple Java project unrelated Maven.

I built the package using "mvn install". Is there a way to find the JAR file so that I can use it in my Java project?

Comment: normally it gets stored in the target folder

Comment: Did you check in the target folder generated by maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `mvn package` or `mvn install` will download the dependency mentioned in your `pom.xml`. And you can find that jar in your IDE under the **external library section**.

Below is the screen-shot of intellij-idea.

[image]

Also actual location of your downloaded jar will be in `~/.m2/repository/` and then you need to go into the `group-id` and `artifact-id` package structure to find it.

Edit :- to search more efficiently using command line use `find . -name "xgboost4*.jar*"` which will output the complete location of jar file like below :-

```
find . -name "xgboost4*.jar*"
./ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/0.6/xgboost4j-0.6.jar.lastUpdated
./ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/0.7/xgboost4j-0.7.jar.lastUpdated
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I found the jars under the .m2/repositories as you suggested.

Comment: glad to know :).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the jar in your local maven repository, ~/.m2/repository/

Maven usually downloads the dependencies from the maven central repo, then save it into your local repo.